# How to decrement each click of the animation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create animation game. Animation game must consits of One image alternating with another every half a second. I am intended to `count++` on each click of the happy-face fish and `count--` on each sad-face fish clicked. But, my code is only incrementing, whatever the image is clicked. Also,my code shows me two different images while It must have to be only one.

I have to count a click while my animation is running ( animation: images should be alternating every half a second. It will look like fish is smiling for half second and then crying for another half second then repeats). If i click on happy face, I will `score` 1 and if click on sad-face I will lose 1. In the end it must show you win if i achieve 10 and resets again on clicking `Start Animation`.

```
[Output should be like this:][1]
```

```js
var image = "happy";
var totalscore = 0;
var counter = 0;
var Schedule;

function happyFish() {
  totalscore++;
  var happyclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
  happyclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
  counter = counter + 1;
  if (counter == 10) {
    clearInterval(Schedule);
    var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
    finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Win!";
  }

}

function sadFish() {
  totalscore--;
  var sadclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
  sadclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
  counter = counter - 1;
  if (counter == -10) {
    clearInterval(Schedule);
    var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
    finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Lose!";
  }
}

function StartAnimation() {
  counter = 0;
  totalscore = 0;
  fish_img = document.getElementById("happy_fish");
  f_img = document.getElementById("happy_fish");
  fish_img.classList.add('on');
  Schedule = setInterval(animationfunction, 500);
}

function animationfunction() {
  if (image == "happy") {
    image = "sad";
    fish_img.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/sad_fish.png";
  } else {
    image = "happy";
    fish_img.src =
      "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png" alt="" id="happy_fish" onClick="happyFish()">
<img src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/sad_fish.png" alt="" id="sad_fish" onClick="sadFish()">
<br>
<h1 id="d">
  Your Score: <span id="score">0</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: count is decreasing when i click the “sad fish", isnt that the correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes, but he mentioned in my answer that he wanted only one fish to show at a time at a 0.5 second interval. (the question isn't very clear)

Comment: "My code shows me two different images while It must have to be only one." I copied this line from the question and it explains that animation should consist of one image alternating with another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your `StartAnimation` and `animationfunction` methods to make the fish dissapear with a toggle instead of trying to modify the source of the image.

I made it with a css class `off` which will make a fish dissapear with `display: none;`

```js
var totalscore = 0;
var counter = 0;
var Schedule;

function happyFish() {
  totalscore++;
  var happyclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
  happyclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
  counter = counter + 1;
  if (counter == 10) {
    clearInterval(Schedule);
    var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
    finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Win!";
  }

}

function sadFish() {
  totalscore--;
  var sadclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
  sadclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
  counter = counter - 1;
  if (counter == -10) {
    clearInterval(Schedule);
    var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
    finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Lose!";
  }
}

function StartAnimation() {
  counter = 0;
  totalscore = 0;
  var initialWords = document.getElementById("d");
    initialWords.innerHTML = "Your Score: <span id=\"score\">0</span>";

  Schedule = setInterval(animationfunction, 500);
}

function animationfunction() {
  var fish_img = document.getElementById("happy_fish");
  var f_img = document.getElementById("sad_fish");

  fish_img.classList.toggle('off');
  f_img.classList.toggle('off');
}
```

```css
.off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="StartAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
<br>
<img src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png" alt="happy" id="happy_fish" onClick="happyFish()">
<img src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/sad_fish.png" alt="sad" id="sad_fish" class="off" onClick="sadFish()">
<br>
<h1 id="d">
  Your Score: <span id="score">0</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: I mistakenly accepted your edit suggestion. But this is not my requirement. It shows two different images of the fish while I only have to work out with one image which is changing every half a second.

Comment: Are you using pure javascript or are you using any framework? (also please add that information to your question)

Comment: I didnt get your question but I am only using javascript and html. I guess it is pure.

Comment: Please review my answer again, I've updated it to meet your requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can make things a lot simpler by having one img element and one click handler.

In the snippet I merged the two click handlers into one and added a check for the state of the fish (being represented now by the boolean isHappy).

I attached this handler to a single img element in your HTML and in the animation function I alternate its src attribute between the happy and sad fish according to the isHappy state.

Additionally, Since the counter and the total score are the same, I use only the total score variable.

```js
var isHappy = true;
var totalscore;
var Schedule;

function clickFish() {
  if (isHappy) {
    totalscore++;
  } else {
    totalscore--;
  }
  var scoreSpan = document.getElementById("score");
  scoreSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
  if (totalscore === 10) {
    clearInterval(Schedule);
    var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
    finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + totalscore + " Game Over. You Win!";
  }
}

function StartAnimation() {
  isHappy = true
  totalscore = 0;
  clearInterval(Schedule);
  Schedule = setInterval(animationfunction, 500);
}

function animationfunction() {
  fish_img = document.getElementById("fish");
  isHappy = !isHappy;
  if (isHappy) {
    fish_img.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png";
  } else {
    fish_img.src = "https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/sad_fish.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="StartAnimation()">Start animation</button><br />
<img src="https://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a5/happy_fish.png" alt="" id="fish" onClick="clickFish()">
<br>
<h1 id="d">
  Your Score:
  <span id="score">0</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: It does not show the start button but it is decrementing each click for the sad face.